# Automatically generating a UI based on the Class that has been passed

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, data-binding, automation

this might be a very basic question but I am cracking my head at this since months. 
I want to create a simple UI for creating objects of the class I pass into the UI constructor.
Let say I have 2 classes:

```
    class Test1
    {
        public static List<Test1> objectList;
        public string code;
        public string name;
    }

    class Test2
    {
        public static List<Test2> objectList;
        public string code;
        public string name;
        public int value;
    }
```

(the static classes would contain all the objects created out of that class)

what I would like to do is to is to create a Code which takes a class as a variable (maybe a generic class?) and based on that creates all the labels and textboxes based on the fields available in the class.
e.g.

```
    public RegisterUI<T> ()
    {
        Grid grd = new Grid();
        DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
        Button saveBtn = new Button();

        //Binding the static list of objects to the DataGrid
        dg.ItemSource = T.objectList;

        //Adding the UI elemnts to the grid
        grd.children.add(dg);
        grd.children.add(saveBtn);

        //Creating for each field in the Class T a lable based on its name and a combobox + binding
        foreach(field in T)
        {
            Lable lbl = new Lable(field.getName);
            ComboBox cbx = new ComboBox();
            grd.children.add(lbl);
            grd.children.add(cbx);
        }
    }
```

Is this even possible? I hope I was not to vague with the mockup code, and you can understand what I am heading for.
Any advice would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  I've done this exact thing for the purpose of automatically creating settings dialogs (I got tired of making a custom form anytime one of my programs had settings that needed modified by the user).

How?

**You're going to need to look into "reflection" which provides you a way to interrogate the structure of objects dynamically.**

I don't use generics for this, but rather interrogate the Type from within the class.

If I pass in `Test1` into my class I get this:

[image]

I wish I could supply source code, but alas, it belongs to my employer.  I can, however, supply a short snippet to get you started:

```
  Type type = typeof(Test1);

  //Get public fields
  List<FieldInfo> fieldInfo = type.GetFields().ToList();

  //Get private fields.  Ensure they are not a backing field.
  IEnumerable<FieldInfo> privateFieldInfo = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(f => !f.Name.Contains("k__BackingField"));

  //Get public properties 
  List<PropertyInfo> properties = type.GetProperties().ToList();

  //Get private properties 
  properties.AddRange(type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that are great hints, i can move on with that.

Comment: @CKnodyvara If you found this answer helpful, please click the "Up Arrow" to vote it up and click the "Check Mark" to mark it as the answer to your question.  You can up vote any answer you found helpful, but only one can be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, looks like something an old demo might help solve:

Note: I'm using JSONs and NewtonSoft's JSON library for my implementation to read a JSON and build the object / UI from that:

```
private void LoadConfig()
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate
        };
        var cfg = ConfigIO.OpenDefault();
        ConfigItem ci = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConfigItem>(cfg.Object);
        IEnumerable<MemberInfo> atts = ConfigInterOps.GetAttributes(typeof(ConfigItem));
        FillForm(ci, atts);
    }

private void FillForm(Object referenceObject, IEnumerable<MemberInfo> atts)
    {
        int location = 5;
        foreach (var att in atts)
        {
            var cfg = new ConfigurationBox(att.Name, referenceObject.GetType()
                .GetProperty(att.Name).GetValue(referenceObject, null));

            cfg.Name = $"cfg_ {att.Name}";
            cfg.Top = 3 * location;
            location += 10;
            Controls["flowLayoutPanel1"].Controls.Add(cfg);                
        }
    }
```

A couple classes I made and use that are referenced above:

```
public static class ConfigInterOps
{
    public static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetAttributes(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetMembers()
            .Where(x => x.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property ||
                x.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field);
    }
}

public static class ConfigIO
{
    public static void Save(Config cfg)
    {
        UseDefaultLocation(cfg);
        if (!File.Exists(cfg.FileLocation))
        {
            File.Create(cfg.FileLocation);
        }
        File.WriteAllText(cfg.FileLocation, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cfg));
    }

    private static void UseDefaultLocation(Config cfg)
    {
        cfg.FileLocation = cfg.FileLocation ?? Path.Combine($"{AppContext.BaseDirectory}", "conf.jobj");
    }

    public static Config OpenDefault()
    {
        var cfg = new Config();
        UseDefaultLocation(cfg);
        return Open(cfg);            
    }

    public static Config Open(Config config)
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText(config.FileLocation);
        Config openedCfg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(text);
        return openedCfg;
    }
}
```

the reference to ConfigurationBox is a custom control:

[image]

And after the config is loaded it looks like:

[image]

Obviously it is rough, but it should provide all the basics you need to do something similar.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. I am not yet familiar with JSON, but I think I will have to get into it.